# Turning personal hotspot on?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Is there a way I can turn personal hotspot on using objective-c? I need to connect to a printer and I don't want the user to go to the settings and then turn it on, rather I want to turn it on in code, print, then turn it back off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do that in the published APIs.

You may want to file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com/

However, I suspect that your use case is sufficiently esoteric that only a few people will be affected. I mean, you have a wifi-enabled printer but no wifi network? That is probably rare for consumers (but common in businesses).

And in the case of businesses, I don't think that they would let their wifi printers connect to any random hotspot that just happens to show up...